# global.gc() doesn't reduce memory after each loop?

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, cheerio

I have one api to crawler, I try use global().gc to reduce heap memory after each loop but it doesn't work. Please point what wrong did I do?
It also leads to heap out of memory problem

```
app.get('/test2', (req, res) => {
```

res.json({mes: 'is getting data'});

array = [...]; //array contains about 1000 element as link

function something() {

```
let d = q.defer();

let urls = [];
    array.forEach(function (mang, index) {
        let tagArray = [];
        tagArray = null;
        tagArray = [];

        //use this function to reduce the memory heap after looping each element of array 
        global.gc();

        for (let i = 1; i <= 4000; i++) {
            urls.push(function (callback) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    let link = 'http://something' + mang.link + '/tag-' + i;
                    //we will have about 4000 links due to i
                    let x = link;

                    let options = {
                        url: link,
                        headers: {
                            'User-Agent': 'MY IPHONE 7s'
                        }
                    };

                    function callback1(error, response, html) {
                        if (!error) {
                            let $ = whacko.load(html);
                            let tag_name = $('h1').text();
                            tag_name = tag_name.trim();
                            console.log(tag_name);
                            let tag_content = $('#content').find('div').contents();
                            tag_content = tag_content.toString();
                            if (tag_name !== "" && tag_content !== "") {

                                let tagObject = new Object();

                                tagObject.tag_name = tag_name;
                                tagObject.tag_content = tag_content;
                                tagObject.tag_number = i;

                                tagArray.push(tagObject);

                                if (tagArray.length == 4000) {
                                    tagArray.sort(function (a, b) {
                                        return parseInt(a.tag_number) - parseInt(b.tag_number);
                                    });

                                    for (let v = 0; v < tagArray.length; v++) {
                                        db.query("INSERT INTO `tags` (tag_name, content, tag_number) " +
                                            "SELECT * FROM (SELECT " + "'" + tagArray[v].tag_name + "'" + "," + "'" + tagArray[v].tag_content + "','" + tagArray[v].tag_number + "' as ChapName) AS tmp " +
                                            "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `tag_name` FROM `tags` WHERE `tag_name`=" + "'" + tagArray[v].tag_name + "'" + ") " +
                                            "LIMIT 1", (err) => {
                                            if (err) {
                                                console.log(err);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    urls = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    request(options, callback1);
                    callback(null, x);
                }, 12000);
            });
        }
    });

    d.resolve(urls);
    return d.promise;
```

}

```
something()
.then(function (data) {
    let tasks = data;
    console.log("start data");
    async.parallelLimit(tasks, 40, () => {
        console.log("DONE ");
    });
})
```

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage?

Comment: I just set "let heapUsed = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;"
then print that variable after each loop.
All I received is about 24-25mb in heap.

Comment: Also, what is your intention with parallel execution?  Are you intending to run `4000 * 1000` requests at once in parallel or are you intending to run them serially one after the other?

Comment: I run 40 requests of 4000 per 12 seconds

Comment: This code appears to create a large array of functions.  Where's the code that actually executes those functions?  I suspect you may be running out of memory because you're running an enormous number of connections at once and thus GC can't save you because lots of memory is in use at the same time.

Comment: @jfriend00 I understand what you say. So all I need is make  the loop run in  sync to run each request in order?

Comment: I was working on a solution, but ran into several questions about what you are trying to accomplish:  1) What do you want to happen if there is an error retrieving the content for one of the URLs (continue or abort)?  2) What are you trying to write into the database and how many times do you want to do that?  3) Why are you setting `urls = null`?  What is the eventual result you want to return from the outer-most promise?  4) Why was their a `setTimeout()`?  Was that just to manage concurrency?